# How to hide a link in a MasterPage and unhide the link based on a certain logged in user?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a web application that has a masterpage and have navigation links. I want to hide one of the links and have it appear when a particular user logs in and I am not sure on how to go approach this.

Right now, when a user logs in I have the user's email address going into SessionState. I am not sure how to unhide the link in the masterpage based on the email address in SessionState.

The project is done with ASP.NET WebForms, I also tagged this question with JQuery because I am thinking on using JQuery to hide the link and possibly use JQuery to unhide it based on the session email and I am not sure if this is the correct way to approach this.

Comment: If you know from the server whether something should be shown/hidden, it's best to show/hide it from ASP.NET web form code behind.  Within master page code-behind, you have access to the User object as a direct property (if not, HttpContext.Current.User has it), which has the Identity object for the current user, or you can check if the user is in the role with IsUserInRole.  Assuming that's how you setup your security.  If you are using the roles provider, then you can use Roles.IsUserInRole from code-behind.

Comment: You should consider using site navigation with sitemaps along with role based authentication. This will enable to apply security trimming to show/hide navigation items. Have a look at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-implement-site-navigation-in-aspnet

Comment: I did something different than what was mentioned, I set the link's visible attribute to false, and when the user logged in I checked the email address and then did used FindControl to find the link and set its visibility to true. I am going to look into both your comments